# Slicing in tf.data causes "iterating over `tf.Tensor` is not allowed in Graph execution" error

Tags: python, tensorflow, slice, tf.data.dataset

I have a dataset created as follows where `image_train_path` is a list of image file paths,
eg. `[b'/content/drive/My Drive/data/folder1/im1.png', b'/content/drive/My Drive/data/folder2/im6.png',...]`. I need to extract the folder paths eg, `'/content/drive/My Drive/data/folder1'` and follow with some other operations. I try to do this using the `preprocessData` function as follows.

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(image_train_path)
dataset = dataset.map(preprocessData, num_parallel_calls=16)
```

where `preprocessData` is:

```
def preprocessData(images_path):
    folder=tf.strings.split(images_path,'/')
    foldername=tf.strings.join(tf.slice(folder,(0,),(6,)),'/')
    ....
```

However, the slicing line causes the following error:

```
OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: in user code:

    <ipython-input-21-2a9827982c16>:4 preprocessData  *
        foldername=tf.strings.join(tf.slice(folder,(0,),(6,)),'/')
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:210 wrapper  **
        result = dispatch(wrapper, args, kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:122 dispatch
        result = dispatcher.handle(args, kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/ragged/ragged_dispatch.py:130 handle
        for elt in x:
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:524 __iter__
        self._disallow_iteration()
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:520 _disallow_iteration
        self._disallow_in_graph_mode("iterating over `tf.Tensor`")
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:500 _disallow_in_graph_mode
        " this function with @tf.function.".format(task))

    OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: iterating over `tf.Tensor` is not allowed in Graph execution. Use Eager execution or decorate this function with @tf.function.
```

I tried this in both Tf2.4 as well as tf nightly. I tried decorating with `@tf.function` as well as using `tf.data.experimental.enable_debug_mode()`. Always gives the same error.

I don't quite understand which part is causing the 'iteration' though I guess the issue is the slicing. Is there an alternate way to accomplish this?

Comment: Could you please post the complete code of `preprocessData`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function [`tf.strings.join`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/strings/join?hl=en) expects a list of Tensor, as the documentation states:

> Args
>
> inputs:   **A list of tf.Tensor objects** of same size and tf.string dtype.

`tf.slice` returns a Tensor, and then the join function will try to iterate over it, causing the error.

You can feed the function with a simple list comprehension:

```
def preprocessData(images_path):
    folder=tf.strings.split(images_path,'/')
    foldername=tf.strings.join([folder[i] for i in range(6)],"/")
    return foldername
```